# Как отлавливать ошибки fetch?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

В моей программе, я вывожу forks репозитория, который вбиваю вручную.

Естественно хочу, в случае, если допущена ошибка ввода, обработать ее, например, вывести сообщение, что данный репозиторий не найден, и чтобы в консоли не было никаких сообщений об ней.

Вот так выглядит рабочий пример без обработки ошибок:

```js
fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/gudh/ihover/forks`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log('+', data))
```

А вот здесь я пытаюсь обработать ошибку, чтобы понять, где мне писать код, который будет выводить сообщение о том, что не найден репозиторий, я вызываю `console.log`, но ни `.catch` ни `try` не вызывают `console.log`, и все равно ошибка падает в консоль.

```js
try {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/gudh/ihove/forks`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log('+', data))
        .catch(() => console.log(12));
} catch (e) {
    console.log(132)
}
```

Если откроете консоль браузера, увидите, что туда попала ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня пишет `
+ {
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks"
}`

Comment: Данную ошибку показывает браузер. Можете скрыть ее в настройках, если она вам не нравится.

Comment: Я хочу выполнить определенный код, когда произойдет ошибка. И чтобы понять, где этот код писать я написал console.log() с "12" и "132", однако ни один console.log не сработал, значит ошибка не отловлена. Я хочу понять, как выполнить какое-либо действие при ошибке с fetch

Comment: Потому что тут не возникает никакой ошибки. Ошибка возникнет, если Вы, например, попытаетесь обратиться к несуществующему серверу. А в данном случае сервер получил запрос, обработал его, и вернул ответ. А если Вас устраивают только ответы с кодом 200, тогда проверяйте `res.status`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как указано в [справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> В отличие от `jQuery.ajax`, Promise, который возвращает `fetch()` переходит в состояние rejected только при ошибке сети или если что-то препятствует завершению запроса. В противном случае наступает состояние resolved, и в случае если HTTP статус соответствует ошибке, например 400 или 500, свойству `ok` устанавливается значение `false`.

Исходя из этого, можно добавить проверку этого свойства, и в зависимости от этого возвращать `Promise.rejected` если требуется.

Например:

```js
fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/gudh/ihove/forks`)
  .then(res => res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res))
  .then(data => console.log('+', data))
  .catch(() => console.log('some error'));
```

Answer (score 6):

Проверяйте статус ответа, формат ответа и т.д.
В случае ошибок, обрывайте цепочку промисов генерацией ошибки:

```
let error = new Error(res.statusText);
throw error
```

Объект `Error` передается в блок `catch`

Если в любом из обработчиков `then` произойдет ошибка javascript, то также сработает блок `catch`

```js
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/gudh/ihove/forks`)
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                return res;
            } else {
                let error = new Error(res.statusText);
                error.response = res;
                throw error
            }
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.headers['content-type'] !== 'application/json') {
                let error = new Error('Некорректный ответ от сервера');
                error.response = res;
                throw error
            }
            return res;
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log('+', data))
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
            console.log(e.response);
        });
```